# how to make 'dirent of' in where clause of a query?

Tags: django

I have this query:

```
countries = Country.objects.filter(country_desc='')
```

How about `country_desc != ''` ?
The query below returns countries which have no descriptions, but for others that have description I had tried this query:

```
countries = Country.objects.filter(~Q(country_desc=''))
```

but it's not working. it returns me a error:

> non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Is there an other efficient way to do it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use exclude instead of filter :)

```
countries = Country.objects.exclude(country_desc='')
```